# Playback not working in offline mode when trying to play offline playlist (libspotify 9.1.32 / armv7 build)

Tags: offline, armv7, spotify

I have an issue with libspotify and playback of offline synchronized playlists. When there is no active internet connection, the login suceeds (and sp_session_connectionstate reports that user is logged-in offline); however playback does not work when trying to play back any track on an offline playlist. Playback does work if logging in with an active internet connection, and then switching the connection off (i.e., seems that it is necessary to be online initially for offline playback to work). Is this an issue with the library, and in such case, can a fix be expected?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt count on a fix from Spotify. They barely listen to the people who use their API.